# php mail() is not sending mails when $headers reach certain length

Tags: php, email, encoding, header, postfix-mta

My PHP `mail()` always stops sending email when the `From` header reaches a certain length. I’m using Cyrillic symbols in the `From` header, so I have to encode it in `windows-1251` (that’s the only encoding that seems to work in all HTML mail clients I need to support).

So, my code:

```
$to = 'myemail@test.com';
$subject = 'Cyrillic subject goes here';
$message = $letterbody; //letterbody gets form data and packs it into nice table
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"; 
//takes Lastname of the person registering, encodes it so all the clients can read, takes its email address
$headers .= "From: =?windows-1251?B?".base64_encode($lastname)."?= <$email>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"\r\n";
mail($to,"=?windows-1251?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=",$message,$headers);
```

So, for example, I set the `$email` variable to `test@test.com` and set  `$lastname` to "tttt". The email sends and `$headers` looks like this (taken from a `var_dump()` right before sending):

> MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>   From: =?windows-1251?B?dHR0dHQ=?=
>   Content-type: text/html; charset="windows-1251"

If I add one more "t" with the same email address

```
$email = test@test.com;
$lastname = "tttttt"
```

the mail does not send and the `$headers` look like this:

> MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>   From: =?windows-1251?B?dHR0dHR0?=
>   Content-type: text/html; charset="windows-1251"

I have no idea what else I can do. With no encoding of the `$lastname` it seems to be working fine, but then it’s unreadable on some email clients, such as Postfix on Ubuntu 13.

Maybe I need to set some `$headers` limit in Postfix?

Comment: **WOW!** That's a **LOT** of header information. You should find an alternative.

Comment: like not encoding a $lastname?

Comment: It seems like it's being over "encoded" if I could say. First it `base64_encode's` the headers, then re-encode's it again in the `mail(...)` function.

Comment: inside the mail() there is $subject that needs to be encoded! in $headers, From: field is encoded. Stupid cyrillic stuff >.>

Comment: Why not declare the `$email` variable (e.g. `$email=$_POST['email'];`) underneath your `$to = 'myemail@test.com';` then pass it in the headers while skipping this part `?windows-1251?B?".base64_encode($lastname)`

Comment: well that way ill get only the email address in From: field, i would like to see it as From: Last Name of the person <email address of the person>

Comment: Ok so why not just combine them in a variable instead, then encode that in one shot? So your `From:` will show up as `From: John Doe`. Just modify your form to have a **first name** and **last name** field, then do `$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];` and `$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];`, then in the header use `From: $firstname $lastname`, something to that affect.

Comment: I want to see From: like this:
From: CyrillicLastName <test@test.com>.
Need to encode LastName so everything can show it up. Dont need to encode email cause its in english already. Dont need the first name here!

Comment: Did you try to omit `=?windows-1251?B?"` I know you need to encode it, but what happens if you leave it out, does it create a problem?

Comment: yeah with no encoding it sends fine on any length, outlook and gmail can read it fine, IBM Notes cant read it and put weird symbols instead. And outlook+lotus notes is 2 main clients used in my company, sadface...

Comment: Hm... ok, a major problem there. How about using an **UTF-8** encoding instead? I researched your issue, but there's a lot of stuff out there, some may help while others may not, and so far `utf-8` seems to have come up on top.

Comment: Sadly but IBM Notes return bad symbols in From: encoded in utf-8 =(

Comment: What if you were to leave out `charset=\"windows-1251\"`. It seems like it's already been declared in `From: =?windows-1251?B?`.

Comment: charset=\"windows-1251\" is for the mail body as far as i know!

Comment: Yes it is part of the mail body, however it might reduce the headers' length at the same time. Give it a try and see. I'm out of options/ideas.

Comment: I guess ill just give up for now and use only <$email> in From:

Comment: Ok. I guess you could always just include it in the email body for you, when emails come in. At least you'll have that recorded somehow. Cheers